# Assign permanent IP address to connecting iPod

Tags: windows-7, ipod-touch, vnc

I use Veency to control my ipod from my desktop. I would like my iPod to be assigned the same IP address every time it connects to my computer. I use Connectivity as an Access Point. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the iPod, go to Settings → Wi-Fi → Blue arrow on your wi-fi network

On this page you'll probably be on the DHCP tab.  You'll want to copy most of the settings from the DHCP tab to the Static tab and leave it set to Static.  The only setting to change is the IP address.  You'll want to use an address that is outside the range of what your access point gives out.  Most access points give out addresses that end in a number higher than 100.

For example, if your IP address right now is 192.168.1.132, you might want to give your iPod a static address of 192.168.1.75.  That way, you know the access point won't give out your address to another computer and cause conflicts.

Comment: when I click the "static" tab, there are no settings visible..should I copy the settings save the IP address from the DHCP tab?

Comment: Yes. The DHCP tab will give you most of the settings, all you need to do is pick a new IP address that your access point won't give out.